# Access public variable in other script using string variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to access a variable from one script using a variable in another script. For example, if I have one script that has this variable:

```
public bool Some_Name;
```

And in my other script I have this:

```
private string nameOfThingToGet = "Some_Name";
...
GameObject.Find ("Player").GetComponent <FirstScript> () .nameOfThingToGet = false;
```

Obviously this wont work, but how would I be able to do something like this?

Comment: Before you go down this road, have you considered making `FirstScript` expose a `Dictionary<string, object>` instead of using fields? This allows for `GameObject.Find ("Player").GetComponent<FirstScript>().dictionary[nameOfThingToGet] = false;`

Comment: Oh, I see thank you for your help.

Comment: That is what I did. got it working perfectly. Thanks again for the help. If you want to submit this as an answer to my question, I would mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you go down this road, have you considered making `FirstScript` expose a `Dictionary<string, object>` instead of using fields?

This allows for you yo do

```
GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<FirstScript>().dictionary[nameOfThin‌​gToGet] = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to achieve it.

```
var obj = GameObject.Find ("Player").GetComponent<FirstScript>();
FieldInfo myFieldInfo = obj.GetField(nameOfTheThingToGet, 
         BindingFlags.Instance);
```

For setting proper flags 
For reference you can visit [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z33zd7h(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I like the reflection solution but since this done in a game engine, [Scott's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45468324/3785314) is highly recommended. It's a matter of Dictionary vs Reflection performance.